# How do I keep/set my CONDA environment variables when sudo PATH=$PATH /opt/lampp/xampp startapache

Tags: xampp, environment-variables, centos7

On centos7 I am trying to deploy my pandas stuff as a webservice using xampp. I am using conda environment. On my ubuntu server I just added the CONDA environment variables as env_keep using visudo, and was able to pass the enviroment to my cgi-bin python script with

sudo PATH=$PATH /opt/lampp/xampp startapache

On centos this does not work. Anyone having approached this problem,- and found a simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could use PassEnv in httpd.conf, so the question is solved (however my script is still not able to import numpy/pandas.)